# Why Promise.all doesn't reject when a non-promise throws an error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all),

> The Promise.all() method takes an iterable of promises as an input,
> and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results
> of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of
> the input's promises have resolved, or if the input iterable contains
> no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises
> rejecting or **non-promises throwing an error**, and will reject with this
> first rejection message / error.

Here is a code-snippet which doesn't catch the error as I expected it to as per above definition :-

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = () => {throw new Error('random error')};
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2(), promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
}).catch(e=>console.log('Error caught',e));
```

I know if I convert the `promise2()` to return a **Promise** which rejects then it will work. But what about the **non-promises** line ? Is it incorrect or am I missing something ?

**Update** - I got the answer for this behavior. Just curious about what could be possible scenarios for **non-promises** throwing an error as per the definition ?

Comment: It's like doing: `const input = [promise1, promise2(), promise3]; Promise.all(input)` Nothing to do with `Promise.all`

Comment: If you wanted it to behave like you're imaging, just pop an `async` in there: `const proimse2 = async () => ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the error is thrown **before** you call `Promise.all`. It's impossible for `Promise.all` to convert that to rejection for you.

You're calling `promise2` when building the array, which happens before you pass that array to `Promise.all`.

Your code here:

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2(), promise3])/*...*/
```

...is equivalent to the following (other than the variables):

```
const x0 = promise1;
const x1 = promise2(); // <==== Error is thrown here
const x2 = promise3;
const array = [x0, x1, x2];
Promise.all(array)/*...*/
```

To make it work as you want, you have several options:

You could make it an `async` function, as [TKoL pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252764/why-promise-all-doesnt-reject-when-a-non-promise-throws-an-error/68252792#comment120627209_68252764) in a comment:

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = async () => {throw new Error('random error')};
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2(), promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
}).catch(e=>console.log('Error caught',e));
```

That works because `async` functions always return promises (even if you don't use `await`) and an error in an async function rejects the promise it returns.

You could make `promise2` a [*thenable*](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7) so it doesn't throw until `then` is called, then `Promise.all` would convert that to rejection for you:

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = {
    then() {
        throw new Error('random error');
    }
};
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

// Note no () on promise2 below
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
}).catch(e=>console.log('Error caught',e));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation. What would be the scenario for a **non-promise** throwing an error ?

Comment: Is the `thenable` object a valid **non-promise** example ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur - Yes. The only way for `Promise.all` to handle converting an error to a rejection is for `Promise.all` to get called and for *it* to call whatever it is that will throw the error. The only thing that `Promise.all` will call is `a then` method. Promises have a `then` method, but for interoperability the Promises/A+ spec linked above (and JavaScript's implementation of it) allow for *thenable* objects (any object with a `then` method).

Answer (score 2):

JS first tries to get the arguments correct - then passes the arguments to the function which is called. In your scenario, an error is thrown even before the `Promise.all` is called.

To better understand the situation and realize that the Promise interface has nothing to do with your case, see the attached snippet. The `PromiseAllTest` function is called with the 3 arguments included in the quesion. But you can see the function is not even called. The error is thrown before it.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = () => {throw new Error('random error')};
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});


try{
  console.log('Preparing to call Promise Test');
  PromiseAllTest([promise1, promise2(), promise3]);  
  console.log('Promise Test is called successfully');
}
catch(e) {
  console.log('Promise Test is not even called')
}

function PromiseAllTest(promiseArray) {
  console.log('Start Processing');
  console.log(promiseArray);
  console.og('End Processing');
}
```